# Magento MassAction grid (custom) Select All not working/not selecting. Why?

Tags: adminhtml, grid, controllers

Magento MassAction grid (custom) Select All not working. Why?

In grid we click `grid_massactionJsObject.selectAll()`(select all link)

**Question**: how can we make select all work again?

Grid.php is set-up like this

```
protected function _prepareMassaction()
{
    $this->setMassactionIdField('item_id');
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('item_ids');
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->setUseSelectAll(true);
```

Select all does nothing

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to apply this fix so setMassactionIdField was respected

https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/pull/150

Answer (score 0):

I have override

> Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Massaction_Abstract class

and i just removed

> var

from the

> getJavaScript()

function and the issue is solved.